# How to Describe the Period of Motion of a Quartic Potential by Elliptic Integral of First Kind

Tags: integration

This is the content of section 1.4 "Instantons and Large N" by Marcos Mariño.

The (inverted) potential is following form.
$$
V(q)=-\frac{1}{2}q^2+\frac{1}{4}q^4
$$
I want to show the period of motion
$$
\beta=2\int_{q_-}^{q_+}\frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\sqrt{2(E-V(q))}}
$$
is equal to
$$
\beta=2\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{2-m}{2}\right)^{1/2}\mathrm{K}(k).
$$

$K(k)$ is the complete elliptic integral of first kind. In addition, $k^2=m=1-\frac{q_-^2}{q_+^2}$ and $q_\pm=\sqrt{1\pm\sqrt{1+4E}}$.

The substitutions ($q=s+q_-,s=(q_+-q_-)t,t=\sin\theta$) don't work well.

The EOM solution is $q(t)=q_+\mathrm{dn}(u;k)$ where $u=\frac{q_+}{\sqrt{2}}(t-t_0),k^2=1-\frac{q_-^2}{q_+^2}$.

The textbook says $E=-\frac{1-k^2}{(2-k^2)^2}$.

How do I transform that integral?

Comment: Link to abstract page?

Answer (score 1):

Use following transformations:
$$
q^2=q_+^2-(q_+^2-q_-^2)s^2,\;s=-t.
$$
The first one's integration range must be from $s=-1$ to $s=0$.